Did Esau sell his birthright under duress?
Genensis 25:29 says:

וַיָּזֶד יַעֲקֹב, נָזִיד; וַיָּבֹא עֵשָׂו מִן-הַשָּׂדֶה, וְהוּא עָיֵף.
And Jacob sod pottage; and Esau came in from the field, and he was faint.

The last word allows various translations: faint, weary, famished, exhausted and hungry, etc.
In a different thread another user suggested that Esau gave up his birthright voluntarily, that he could have obtained food from other sources, and that anyhow he despised his birthright. It seems to me as an argument intended to prove the infallibility of Jacob, but inconsistent with what the text actually says.
Indeed, whatever were Esau's feelings towards his birthright, he didn't intend to give it up - he tried later to get his father's blessing and was angry at Jacob for stealing it. The sale itself was also an illegal act, which prompted Jacob to play the ruse on Isaac.
In other words, Jacob gets his birthright by means of a double fraud - I don't see such an interpretation as problematic: Jacob has many virtues which qualify him for precedence over Esau (even if these do not include being honest vis-à-vis Esau, Isaac or Laban.) This is also consistent with the larger text, which portrays a chain of humanly flawed characters (Abraham, Jacob, Moses, David), which are not free of sin, but strive to do their best. After all, even YHWH occasionally seems to admit his mistakes - e.g., when promising to never again destroy mankind after the flood or in Exodus 32:9-10.
Comparing relevant interpretations from different religions/religious currents interests me as well.
Remark
In view of the objections in the comments to the very idea that Jacob might be committing a fraud, let me comment, e.g., this Catholic view:

Justus Knecht comments that: "The Wisdom of God, which makes good come out of evil, can be learnt from this story. Almighty God had from the beginning, or rather from all eternity, chosen Jacob to be the heir of His promises. The faults of men (such as Isaac's preference for Esau, Jacob's deceit, and Esau's hatred) could not alter what He had ordained; on the contrary, they served, under the divine guidance, for the accomplishment of it. Jacob, especially, was strengthened in confidence in God, and purified by the very consequences of his deceit, his long exile and servitude. He was by them confirmed in humility and piety, and trained to be a holy man of God, and the worthy heir of the promises."[29]


The answer is, he probably did.  However, that duress was of Esau's own making - his uncontrolled appetite.

@NigelJ you downvote for disagreeing with your religious beliefs? IMHO, this disagrees with the SE policy. I take a schreenshot for the meta.

@NigelJ voting is supposed to be on the merits of the content, not on your opinions or likes. I don't think this community is different from the rest of the SE in this respect.

@NigelJ I have not commented on how I vote or when I vote or if I vote. - since you are high-ranked user in this community, you probably know that SE keeps track of all the edits - so the moderators will be able to consult the previous version of your first comment. A good reason to avoid making claims that can be proven untrue.

@NigelJ you are speaking from the position of your religious beliefs - which happen to be different from mine... and you seem to have no a priori respect for the latter.

@NigelJ I suppose some Christian denominations might equate Jacob with Jesus (whom they consider infallible), but many would consider such an equivalence blasphemous. Furthermore, I don't think rigorously analyzing a historical text can be hurtful to anyone's beliefs - otherwise one is simply being dishonest with oneself... and perhaps also with the Almighty.

There was another reason selling the birthright was beneficial to Esau - the promised land stil belonged to descendants of Iaphet and Esau probably had to be sacrificed in the same way Isaak was to avoid the collusion. This problem was first resolved by events happened around and with Moses. Maybe this will help to find an insight into your question.

@Roger V Now that is something I am able to comment on. You accept he is 'Almighty'. Yet you say he makes 'mistakes'. That seems untenable to me on purely logical grounds.

@NigelJ almighty and infallible are not the same thing. Even a local mafia boss could be called almighty, because he knows everything and controls life&death of everyone in the neighborhood - yet he is neither infallible, nor even immortal. But I might be using terms Almighty/YHWH simply out of respect for believers - one could entertain the possibility of His existence without accepting it. This is not unlike your editing and deleting your previous remarks - it shows more concern for the opinion of other users than for what He might think, despite the professions of faith.

@RogerV. I cannot accept the mythical concept of a human on earth being able to 'control life & death in the neighbourhood' and 'knowing everything'. My mind is not able to accept such a concept. And yes, many people 'entertain the possibility of God's existence' but they do not love Him and do not entrust their being to Him.  Yes, it is quite common.

@NigelJ Loving and entrusting oneself to God are a part of Christian theology, which stresses the mystical personal relation between a person and the Almighty. This is by no means general to all the religions - Jews and Muslims would probably say that fearing God and following the law is more important than personal feelings. But we stray off the subject, which is against the SE rules.

@RogerV. It has been useful to exchange comments for now I have a better understanding of what it is that you are actually asking. (Did he indeed 'sell' ? Was there really anything to sell ? Did this 'story' ever happen ? ) So now I have cancelled my close vote and I shall begin to prepare a cogent answer. Regards.

To grasp the significance of what happened when Esau returned from a long hunting trip, faint with hunger, bear in mind that he couldn't just switch on a microwave and heat up a ready-cooked meal. It took hours to prepare a meal of any substance, which is what he desperately needed. And there was his twin brother, with a pot of delicious-smelling, hot stew, in the pot!
Now, what happened next showed up Jacob's true character. No way was he "infallible"! Yet knowing the family history and what happened in later years proves that what Jacob did then, and later, was entirely legal. It caused God's will to be done, which had been prophetically stated way back.
First, cosider the names given to the twins. The older twin was named Esau because it was a play on his body having red hair. Jacob's name came from 'heel' and 'deceiver' as he was born grasping the heel of his brother, and the deceiver bit prophetically showed his character. Esau's character was 'of the [red] earth', being a hunter of game, and so taken was he with material things that he sold his birth-right for a meal of red stew. Jacob appreciated the value of the birth-right and cunningly prised it from his brother, playing on his brother's weakness. Esau showed contempt for his birth-right.
Jacob's mother later instructed him how to get the birth-right before his father died, through deception. Talk about living up to one's name! But the Lord dealt severely with Jacob, finally purging him of his carnal methods so that in his old age God changed his name to Israel (which means 'God fights').
The dying father realized Jacob had tricked him to get the first-born's birth-right, only after he'd blessed Jacob. There was a time lapse before Esau pointed out the trickery. When he begged for a blessing too, Isaac did have one, but because of the covenant nature of such blessings of inheritance, once stated they could not be changed. That pronouncement to Jacob had been an oracle from God, through Isaac's lips, and he knew it.
Bear in mind that the blessing was not false. In Genesis 27:33 Isaac began to tremble uncontrollably at the realization of what had happened, yet he told Esau "That blessing must stand!" God used events to overrule the natural order to fulfil prophecy about the twins. Read Genesis 25:21-26. Now Jacob had been made Esau's master! The older did, indeed, end up serving the younger. See Genesis 27:37-40. Once the deception was in the open, Isaac then gave Esau another blessing based on what he now knew God wanted him to do.
Finally, all this was linked to the prophecy in Genesis 3:15 as to "the seed of the woman" - it had to come through Jacob - Israel. But Jacob did not have to be "infallible". Yes, he used cunning, yes he used trickery and lied to his near-blind father. But his mother knew the prophecy at the birth of the twins, and played her part in the word that God gave to her coming true.
So, the simple answer to the main question is "Yes, physical duress that Esau could not bear, so prompting him to be tempted by food at the expense of God's blessing." He probably thought Jacob could never secure the birth-right and promptly forgot his promise the moment he tucked in. But verbal promises in the Bible are seriously important, unlike today in modern society. On the other hand, whatever God says comes true, and what he'd foretold to the twins' mother at their birth came true with the birth-right.

"physical duress that Esau could not bear, so prompting him to be tempted by food at the expense of God's blessing" — He'd simply been doing hard physical labour in the field, saw Jacob's food, and felt hungry. That his own immediate and temporary discomfort was more important to him than his birthright is a strong proof that the didn't deserve it. Or perhaps Esau was the deceptive one, making a promise to Jacob that he had no intention of keeping. Yes, Jacob took unfair advantage of Esau, but it was done honestly and openly, not as a trick.

Human beings can go without food for days.  Being unable to bear the delay for some hours is a moral flaw on Esau's part.

It doesn't even say it was a hunting expedition.  But, were that true, the lack of foresight to bring adequate provisions or to simply return home when they were exhausted is the same issue.  Both Jacob and Abraham had to do thing as part of God's plan that required they endure suffering for the reward that was to come.  Lacking the foresight to do that means you aren't fit for the task.


The first humanity is of the earth, earthy. The second humanity is the Lord from heaven. [1 Corinthians 15:47 Literal]


And it came to pass, as he drew back his hand, that, behold, his brother came out: and she said, How hast thou broken forth? this breach be upon thee: therefore his name was called Pharez. [Genesis 38:29 KJV]


The narrative of the text of Genesis 27 is clearly spiritual. Natural matters are recounted as they occurred, providentially, in order to set forth spiritual truth.
It would be pointless to read the book of Genesis if one could not accept that ‘in the beginning, God created’. Or that ‘Jacob went on his way and the angels of God met him’. What would be the point ? And even if one did, one could garnish no truth from a disbelieved narrative. One could learn no lessons from a text which was incomprehensibly merged with fantastical nonsense.
Isaac was the seed of promise, the monogenes, that one of a new generation who was singular, especial, having a closeness, an uncommon bond, beyond the natural relationship. Yet Isaac was now old and his eyes were dim. And he loved the hairy, macho hunter and he loved the venison.
Nature had taken over within Isaac ; and spiritual matters had become dim.
This is a lesson to be learned when an older generation fails the new. They cannot be rebelled against. They still deserve their honour. But they cannot be counted on to make further spiritual progress.
Thus we have an entire chapter devoted to expediencies, taken to surmount the problem of . . . .  Isaac favouring the wrong seed.
For 'Jacob have I loved and Esau have I hated' : before they were even born.
The dream comes to Rebekah, not to Isaac. It  is she who receives the promise. ‘The elder shall serve the younger.’ She later assists her second born to supplant the first, even if she be cursed in the doing of it.
For this is a matter of generation and of inheritance. For Eve was promised a seed, not of man ; a seed who, from above, would bruise the head of the serpentine spirit who attempts to seize the creation from the rightful ownership of the Creator.
And this seed of promise is followed in the genealogies and narratives of the Hebrew scriptures. If that is not seen and followed then the whole is just chaotic and senseless : mere fantastical rituals without foundation in logic. Sheer superstition with no basis in sound fact.
Follow the promise : and all becomes clear.


... and he weary ...
[Genesis 25:29 both Biblehub Interlinear and Young's Literal Translation]
[there is no verb present]

עָיֵֽף׃ ageph 'faint, weary' Strong 5889
Compare with  Samuel 17:29 'hungry and weary and thirsty'

Whatever the subtlety of the Hebrew word, Esau was no worse off than multitudes on planet earth who daily go to bed hungry, exhausted with excessive labour yet under-nourished. His complaint is exaggerated, excessive, not realistic.
Such concept is typical of the self-centred and the narcissistic. They create their own reality and are oblivious to the reality of others around them.
The tent-dwelling soup-cooking second-born would not have attempted to coerce the hairy hunter fresh in from his day’s labours clattering his weapons about him as he enters the tent  . . . . .
. . . . . unless Jacob had previously seen ample evidence of an inward state of heart that was already well established : the despising of the birthright.
This was deeper than just having an advantage of inheritance over his brother. Far, far more was at stake.
The seed of promise.
Eve’s seed yet to come.
The ascension of One over angelic powers.
The ascending of the Promised One over the Usurper of the Creation.
This is what Esau despised : the spirituality of what Isaac and Rebekah lived for.
And Jacob too.
This ; the whole point of the Hebrew narrative of Genesis, and every book that would follow, and all that would continue to follow in Greek.
The whole content of Holy scripture ; God-breathed words.
The entire revelation unfolding over two and a half millenia (Job 2,400 B.C. ; Moses 1,500 B.C. ; David 1,000 B.C. ; Jesus of Nazareth - the splitting of time into two).
This is what Esau despised.
And complained of no more than billions of people around the globe suffer repeatedly.
And having despised, it is taken from him. And given to another. Which was already seen and known aforehand, when they were both in the womb.

Duress ?
I think not.
No, he despised spiritual matters of great import.
And once he rejected, there was no going back and trying again.
Only a certain looking for of judgment.
And an unchangeable destiny.
What an example not to follow.

Thank you. This is a somewhat new perspective for me - if the OT is viewed as a spiritual document, a formulated of the principles of faith, then you interpretation seems very logical. I tend to view OT as a historical document, which records in allegorical form some historical events and/or evolution of human beliefs... but even from this perspective you are probably right, that author's intention was to show how lightly Esau took spiritual matters. Your remarks about Isaac are also very convincing - the text is clearly much richer than I thought when asking my question.

@RogerV. Thank you. Glad to be of service.


And the LORD said unto her, Two nations are in thy womb, and two manner of people shall be separated from thy bowels; and the one people shall be stronger than the other people; and the elder shall serve the younger. - Genesis 25:23

Was Esau under duress?  I suppose, if we take his statement of verse 32 "I am about to die, what good will my birthright do me then." at face value rather than hyperbole, we must answer affirmative.  What we don't know from the text is how much duress he was actually in.
How much duress to sell so cheaply a double portion, 2/3, of his Father's expansive estate?  How much duress to set aside the surety of the full and sole mantle of authority over family, servants, goods, and lands?
Even if we disregard the weight of spiritual blessing the firstborn will receive and focus on just the physical (which I suggest Esau did) it seems unlikely he was that close to the point of death.  Esau ate bread and lentils and rose up and went his way (verse 34).  He probably was not on the brink of death to have recovered so quickly.

The Lord Jesus was 40 days in the wilderness without food; driven there by the Spirit to be tested.  I would like to suppose he was hungrier than Esau.  Regardless, along comes Satan offering a short cut to satisfy the flesh to which Jesus replies, "There's more to the sustenance of life than physical food (paraphrase)."
We see Jesus responding as without sin and we see Jacob and Esau responding as sinful.  Two men from one womb: Fraternal not identical.  Both "in Adam", both sinners and yet two manner of men as the Scriptures record.
One of sinful flesh unwilling to prioritize spiritual things.  One of sinful flesh willing to cheat to attain them.  One whose flesh will only attune to itself.  One who is willing to have his flesh put out of joint to attain something greater.  One who is hated and the other who is loved, in the foreknowledge of God, before they had done anything.
This is the great lesson of Isaac's offspring, in whom Abraham's seed are called.  We are all under duress of sin.  Some will not receive spiritual things even though it is birthright because the immediate and physical trumps the spiritual.  Others will receive spiritual things and are, in spite of the immediate and physical, teachable though they seek shortcuts.  One will be hated and the other loved.
Two nations. Jacob becomes Israel.  Edom is gone.  Two manner of men remain.  Not all Israel (of the nation) are Israel (of the promise), says Paul.  Natural descent avails nothing (Romans 9).  A believing remnant of Jews and believing gentiles come together in Christ (Romans 10) and, in this way, all Israel (of the promise) will be saved (Romans 11).
Out of twain, Jew and Gentile, one new man will be made, in Christ, the singular promised seed and the Israel of God.  The great personal question is, What manner of man am I.  All who will may come.
